# Mesh not updating face or vertex colors

Tags: react-three-fiber

I am using react-three-fiber and I cannot get updated `mesh` and `vertex` colors to display.  The color of my mesh stays the same even after I do all the steps below:

I have the following code which creates a `mesh`:

```
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xffffff,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.5,
        wireframe: false,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        vertexColors: true,
      });
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(curvedGeometry, material);
```

I then render that mesh using a `primitive` component

```
<primitive object={mesh} />
```

Later, I change the face and vertex colors in that mesh.  So that all the vertices and faces have the color values in the picture below:

[image]

Finally, I set the colorsNeedUpdate value on the geometry to true like this

```
polygonMesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Code sandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/change-vertex-colors-old-rz82v?runonclick=1&file=/src/index.tsx:665-673

Comment: Hey reggie, can you setup a code sandbox?

Comment: @Will Sandbox link added